# Titanium Desktop createProcess to run shell script

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium, desktop-application

I'm new to Titanium and am trying to create a small test.  I am on a Mac and trying to run the  following code:

```
<a id="btn-file" href="#">Create File</a>
        
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn-file").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var process = Titanium.Process.createProcess(
            ['touch', 'file.txt']
        );
    });
</script>
```

However, file.txt is not created.  How do I run a terminal command from Titanium Desktop?  Eventually, I'd like to click btn-file and it runs a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to the "launch" method. You create the process, but don't do anything with it!

```
<a id="btn-file" href="#">Create File</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn-file").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var process = Titanium.Process.createProcess(
            ['touch', 'file.txt']
        );
        process.launch();
    });
</script>
```