# Execute Shell command in tideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I need to run a shell command, that will call the script file that I have written in RUBY

For eg: Lets say, I have a file.sh in my working directory, How can I execute this file using TideSDK( I tried Using the Process)

[Titanium Desktop createProcess to run shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053883/titanium-desktop-createprocess-to-run-shell-script)

Is there some other alternatives for this kind of stuffs in tideSDK?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I need to run the ruby script after a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to run a process for that. TideSDK allows you to run other scripts like php, ruby and python directly in script tags. On the tag you just need to define the script on the type attribute: text/ruby

There ar several methods to include scripts on TideSDK. Take a look on the documentation at www.tidesdk.org. There is a section related to how to get started.

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/using_ruby

Comment: However, This would run when the page loads rite. In my case I need to run particular script after some action like clicking a button. So in that case what should I do?